# Simplifying a double summation to find alpha

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, summation

**Background**

In studying probability, I came across a question asking to find a constant of proportionality alpha that determines a discrete joint probability distribution. The exercise has a solution, however, there is little explanation provided which has made it quite hard to follow. I’ve detailed my progress and also what parts I am stuck with below.

**The Question**

Find the value of $\alpha > 0$ such that, for all $m,n \in \{0,1,2,3$…$\}$:

$$P(X=m, Y=n) = \alpha \frac{2m+n}{m!n!} (p)^{m+n}$$

**My Attempt**

It is clear that if we sum over all values of $m$ and $n$, then this should be equal to $1$ by the properties of the joint density density function - i.e.

$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha \frac{2m+n}{m!n!} (p)^{m+n} =1$$

By splitting up the fraction, we see that this is equivalent to:

$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2m}{m!n!} (p)^{m+n} + \frac{n}{m!n!} (p)^{m+n} =\frac{1}{\alpha}$$

However, I am unsure of how to proceed from here.

The model solution says that this can be rewritten as:

$$3\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha \frac{1}{m!n!} (p)^{m+1+n} =1$$

It’s both parts of this line that are unclear to me. I don’t understand how the expression on the left hand side is arrived at. And I also don’t see how this simplifies to give us the required result to solve for alpha.

I would be grateful for any help in understanding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: In your first sum
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2m}{m!n!} (p)^{m+n} $$
the sum over $m$ can start at $m=1$ instead of $m=0$. Now define a new index of summation, say $M:=m-1$ and rewrite in terms of $M$. With this new index, the sum over $M$ begins at zero.

To simplify the expression that you obtain, notice that you can factor into the product of two sums over $M$ and $n$. You should be able to detect a sum of the form $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!},$$ which is the power series expansion for $e^x$.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to work my way to the correct answer from there. It didn’t cross my mind that redefining the index could help to simplify the sum.